# How to efficiently fill an incomplete pandas dataframe consisting of pairwise combinations of values in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a list of values,

```
lst=['orange','apple','banana', 'grape', 'lemon']
```

I also have a pandas dataframe of the form, `df`:

```
Source     Destination     Weight
orange     apple           0.4
banana     orange          0.67
grape      lemon           0.1
grape      banana          0.5
```

The rows are a subset of all pairwise combinations in lst. Note that every combination appears at most once.

What I want is a new dataframe where the remaining combinations are filled in with a value of 0.

For example, `new_df`:

```
Source     Destination     Weight
orange     apple           0.4
banana     orange          0.67
grape      lemon           0.1
grape      banana          0.5
orange     grape           0.0
orange     lemon           0.0
banana     lemon           0.0
```

The order does not make a difference.

What is a fast way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- I create an array of sets of combinations
- Then I do the same thing for the combinations that already exist
- I use `np.in1d` to find the ones that don't exist
- Then append a new dataframe with the ones that don't exist yet.

---

```
from itertools import combinations

comb = np.array([set(x) for x in combinations(lst, 2)])
exst = df[['Source', 'Destination']].apply(set, 1).values
new = comb[~np.in1d(comb, exst)]

d1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [list(x) for x in new],
    columns=['Source', 'Destination']
).assign(Weight=0.)

df.append(d1, ignore_index=True)

   Source Destination  Weight
0  orange       apple    0.40
1  banana      orange    0.67
2   grape       lemon    0.10
3   grape      banana    0.50
4   grape      orange    0.00
5  orange       lemon    0.00
6   apple      banana    0.00
7   grape       apple    0.00
8   apple       lemon    0.00
9  banana       lemon    0.00
```

Comment: Maybe, I go where my brain takes me.  Get down one answer then search for more... looking now (-:

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I notice that we get duplicates by doing this. For example, banana/orange had a value of 0.67, but another row- orange/banana gets added with a value of 0.0. Is there a way to not add those rows?

Comment: @Melsauce I didn't even think of that... I'll have to fix or come up with something different.  Deleting answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Convert your source dataframe to a frozenset

```
In [350]: df = df.assign(Combinations=df.apply(lambda x: frozenset(x[:-1]), axis=1)).loc[:, ['Combinations', 'Weight']]
```

Step 2: Generate all possible combinations (`import itertools` first) of items from `lst`

```
In [352]: new_df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(lst, 2)), columns=['Source', 'Destination'])
```

Step 3: Merge on combinations

```
In [358]: new_df = new_df.iloc[:, :2].apply(lambda x: frozenset(x), axis=1)\
                        .to_frame().rename(columns={0 : "Combinations"})\
                        .merge(df, how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Step 4: Revert to original structure

```
In [365]: new_df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x['Combinations'])), axis=1)\
                .rename(columns={0 : 'Source', 1 : 'Destination'})\
                .join(new_df['Weight'])
Out[365]: 
   Source Destination  Weight
0  orange       apple    0.40
1  orange      banana    0.67
2   grape      orange    0.00
3  orange       lemon    0.00
4   apple      banana    0.00
5   grape       apple    0.00
6   apple       lemon    0.00
7   grape      banana    0.50
8   lemon      banana    0.00
9   grape       lemon    0.10
```

Comment: Same problem as mine... OP wants indifference between `('orange', 'apple')` and `('apple', 'orange')`

Comment: @piRSquared How about now? I've had to bite the bullet. This is really long winded.

Comment: What happened to banana, orange being .67

Comment: @piRSquared Updated :>

Comment: Me too.  rounding out with some explanation.